# OpenGL Without GUI

Tags: linux, opengl, glut, xorg, glx

Let's say I run a Linux and I have no desktop environment installed. I boot up my system and all I have is my shell.

Is it possible to compile a program  that uses the OpenGL libraries or directly uses the GPU driver to draw to the screen?

As far as I could understand I would always need some kind of desktop environment that would provide me a window that I can draw on. To keep it 
 simple let's say I just want to draw a simple 2d shape like a triangle in the middle of the screen for example.

And if that's possible how can I do it and where can I read more about the topic? If I am able to draw directly over my terminal does this mean that I would be able to run my app on a system that has a desktop environment and still be able to see my triangle?

Comment: Can I do it without a X server and do the job that the X server is normally doing?

Comment: Does https://www.mesa3d.org/osmesa.html help?

Comment: This can render my content to a buffer in memory but how do I render that buffer to the screen after that?

Comment: @KaloyanManev: I just have to point this out, for you (and the rest of the readers), for future reference. This (*again…*) is a prime example of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You thought that somehow getting direct access to graphics memory, would allow you to draw some overlay over the rest of the GUI, so you'd asked about talking to the GPU directly without a windowing system, omitting what your actual goal is. Ergo you got an answer how to use the GPU without a windowing system, which didn't solve your *actual* problem.

Comment: @KaloyanManev: Take this as a lesson for the future: __*ALWAYS*__ ask about the actual task you try to accomplish. If you have to ask about it, that means, that you also lack understanding of how this problem can be actually addressed in the first place. You might have a guess what could be a part of the solution, and this guess might actually be sensible in a different context. But it doesn't help you there. So always ask, what it really is, what you're trying to do. Then you'll get to your goal much faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to compile a program that uses the OpenGL libraries or directly uses the GPU driver to draw to the screen?

Yes. With the EGL API this has been formalized and works most well with NVidia GPUs and their proprietary drivers. NVidia has it described on their dev blog here https://devblogs.nvidia.com/egl-eye-opengl-visualization-without-x-server/

Essentially the steps are:

Create a OpenGL context for a PBuffer

```
#include <EGL/egl.h>

  static const EGLint configAttribs[] = {
          EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
          EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
          EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
          EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
          EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 8,
          EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_BIT,
          EGL_NONE
  };    

  static const int pbufferWidth = 9;
  static const int pbufferHeight = 9;

  static const EGLint pbufferAttribs[] = {
        EGL_WIDTH, pbufferWidth,
        EGL_HEIGHT, pbufferHeight,
        EGL_NONE,
  };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // 1. Initialize EGL
  EGLDisplay eglDpy = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

  EGLint major, minor;

  eglInitialize(eglDpy, &major, &minor);

  // 2. Select an appropriate configuration
  EGLint numConfigs;
  EGLConfig eglCfg;

  eglChooseConfig(eglDpy, configAttribs, &eglCfg, 1, &numConfigs);

  // 3. Create a surface
  EGLSurface eglSurf = eglCreatePbufferSurface(eglDpy, eglCfg, 
                                               pbufferAttribs);

  // 4. Bind the API
  eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_API);

  // 5. Create a context and make it current
  EGLContext eglCtx = eglCreateContext(eglDpy, eglCfg, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, 
                                       NULL);

  eglMakeCurrent(eglDpy, eglSurf, eglSurf, eglCtx);

  // from now on use your OpenGL context

  // 6. Terminate EGL when finished
  eglTerminate(eglDpy);
  return 0;
}
```

and then go about the rest as per usual. Or you can even ditch the PBuffer completely and just use OpenGL manages resources, i.e. render to framebuffer objects. For that end you can omit creating the surface and just make the context current.

Here's an example for using EGL without display, no EGL surface, with OpenGL managed framebuffer.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

namespace render
{
    int width, height;
    float aspect;

    void init();
    void display();

    int const fbo_width = 512;
    int const fbo_height = 512;

    GLuint fb, color, depth;

    void *dumpbuf;
    int dumpbuf_fd;
};

static const EGLint configAttribs[] = {
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_BIT,
    EGL_NONE
};   

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // 1. Initialize EGL
    EGLDisplay eglDpy = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    EGLint major, minor;    
    eglInitialize(eglDpy, &major, &minor);

    // 2. Select an appropriate configuration
    EGLint numConfigs;
    EGLConfig eglCfg;

    eglChooseConfig(eglDpy, configAttribs, &eglCfg, 1, &numConfigs);

    // 3. Bind the API
    eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_API);

    // 3. Create a context and make it current
    EGLContext eglCtx = eglCreateContext(eglDpy, eglCfg, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, 
    NULL);

    eglMakeCurrent(eglDpy, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_SURFACE, eglCtx);

    glewInit();
    // from now on use your OpenGL context
    render::init();
    render::display();

    // 4. Terminate EGL when finished
    eglTerminate(eglDpy);
    return 0;
}

void CHECK_FRAMEBUFFER_STATUS()
{                                                         
    GLenum status;
    status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER); 
    switch(status) {
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
        break;

    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:
    /* choose different formats */
        break;

    default:
        /* programming error; will fail on all hardware */
        throw "Framebuffer Error";
    }
}

namespace render
{
    float const light_dir[]={1,1,1,0};
    float const light_color[]={1,0.95,0.9,1};

    void init()
    {
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
        glGenTextures(1, &color);
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depth);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color);
        glTexImage2D(   GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                0, 
                GL_RGB8, 
                fbo_width, fbo_height,
                0, 
                GL_RGBA, 
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                NULL);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, color, 0);

        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, fbo_width, fbo_height);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth);

        GLint red_bits, green_bits, blue_bits, alpha_bits;

        glGetIntegerv(GL_RED_BITS,   &red_bits);
        glGetIntegerv(GL_GREEN_BITS, &green_bits);
        glGetIntegerv(GL_BLUE_BITS,  &blue_bits);
        glGetIntegerv(GL_ALPHA_BITS, &alpha_bits);

        fprintf(stderr, "FBO format R%dG%dB%dA%d\n",
            (int)red_bits,
            (int)green_bits,
            (int)blue_bits,
            (int)alpha_bits );

        CHECK_FRAMEBUFFER_STATUS();

        dumpbuf_fd = open("/tmp/fbodump.rgb", O_CREAT|O_SYNC|O_RDWR, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
        assert(-1 != dumpbuf_fd);
        dumpbuf = malloc(fbo_width*fbo_height*3);
        assert(dumpbuf);
    }

    void render()
    {
        static float a=0, b=0, c=0;

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

        glViewport(0,0,fbo_width, fbo_height);

        glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1,0,0);
        glVertex3f(1,0,0);

        glColor3f(0,1,0);
        glVertex3f(0,1,0);

        glColor3f(0,0,1);
        glVertex3f(0,0,1);
        glEnd();

        glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
       glReadPixels(0,0,fbo_width,fbo_height,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,dumpbuf);
        lseek(dumpbuf_fd, SEEK_SET, 0);
        write(dumpbuf_fd, dumpbuf, fbo_width*fbo_height*3);
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can understand this creates a buffer, draws and finally saves it to /tmp/fbodump.rgb?

Comment: @KaloyanManev: Yes, that it does indeed. You can display the file generated by this example with the `display` tool of ImageMagick like this: `display -size 512x512 -depth 8 RGB:/tmp/fbodump.rgb` – I just cobbled together this example from various code lying around: The EGL code from the NVidia blog, some ancient framebuffer tutorial code I wrote ages ago and then threw in some immediate mode stuff, because I couldn't be bothered to go full VBO. But I tested it with NVidia proprietary and Mesa intel_dri drivers and it works (at least here).

Comment: Yeah I see, I also found some tutorials on how to do rendering in a buffer. About the displaying part I was asking if I can render the buffer on top of my my running GUI without creating a window.

Comment: @KaloyanManev: On Linux you can in fact use EGL to do that, however I never tried it so far. If you can live with not supporting NVidia GPUs, then you may have a look at GBM which allows to directly access the GPU without going through a display system. There's a demo called [`kmscube`, which shows how to do that](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/kmscube/). Also if you want to *bypass* the windowing system for a specific device (say a VR headset or some non-desktop display) there's now [DRM leases](https://keithp.com/blogs/DRM-lease/) in the works, just for doing that.

Comment: I just tried both kmscube and another drm leases example called jesse-cube, both wokring in console mode. When tried with GUI only the jesse-cube works and it is inside a window. I think it is impossible to access the video memory and just draw over the desktop environment. That would be too hacky and would probably required a custom driver. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KaloyanManev: Ah, now I get what you want to do. You want to draw an __*overlay*__ over the whole desktop. *First things first:* It doesn't work the way you imaging. You can't simply "draw over" the video memory. Because on modern GPUs there's not "the" video memory, but a whole bunch of buffers, that are constantly redrawn and cycled through, called a *swap chain* (you might now that term, if you've been dabbling with Vulkan). So that's the bad news.

Comment: @KaloyanManev: The good news is: You don't need to resort to crude hacks. Modern graphics systems employ compositing (or are at least enable to do it out of the box). That means, that you can write a program, that takes all the individual windows and draws them in any matter you like, applying all kinds of effects. That is done by so called "compositor" program. Wayland is designed around compositor. X11 has the *Composite* extension. What comes down to, for *you* is, that you can simply write a program, that creates a window that overlays everything, but has a fully functional alpha channel.

Comment: @KaloyanManev: If you're running X11 and use a Composite enabled window manager (GNOME Shell, KDE KWin, Ubuntu Unity, Mate Marco), then this works out of the box. Otherwise, simply install and run `xcompmgr`. Then head over to https://git.datenwolf.net/codesamples/ clone the repository and try out the [x11argb_opengl_glsl](https://git.datenwolf.net/codesamples/tree/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl_glsl/x11argb_opengl_glsl.c) sample inside it. To adopt it for your needs, create the window with [Override Redirect](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/attributes/override-redirect.html), fullscreen.